# cant get variable value in node js

Tags: node.js

I tried to make the function async but when I print the attacks it prints out {} without anything in it but when I print the values right after adding them in attacks I can print them why is it like that? how can I use the value?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

var attacks = {};

var phase_name;

var directory = 'cti-master\\enterprise-attack\\attack-pattern\\';

// getting all files names.
async function getData(directory){
fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => { 
    if(err) { return;}
    var fileNum = 0;
    
    // opening all the files and sorting the data in them.
    while (fileNum < files.length - 1)
    {

        fs.readFile(directory + files[fileNum], 'utf8', (err, data) =>
        {
            // parsing the data from json.
            var fileData = JSON.parse(data);

            // sometimes there is no phase name.
            if(fileData['objects'][0]['kill_chain_phases'] == undefined){phase_name = undefined;}
            else{phase_name = fileData['objects'][0]['kill_chain_phases'][0]['phase_name'];}

            // sorting data by name to make it easier later.
            attacks[fileData['objects'][0]['name']] = {
                id: fileData['objects'][0]['id'],
                type: fileData['objects'][0]['type'],
                description: fileData['objects'][0]['description'],
                x_mitre_platforms: fileData['objects'][0]['x_mitre_platforms'],
                x_mitre_detection: fileData['objects'][0]['x_mitre_detection'],
                phase_name: phase_name};
        }); 
        fileNum += 1;
    };
}); 
    var keys = Object.keys(attacks);
    console.log(attacks);
}

getData(directory);
```

Comment: readFile reads the content of the given file **asynchronously**. This is why when you log out the content of your object attacks inside the fs method, you are able to see the object fields as expected. You cannot see the same output when you log this out right after the asynchronous method because the script does not **await** the readFile method...

Comment: then how do i use the attacks value outside of the function?

Comment: One of the options you have is to use a callback function passing the object you want to manipulate in as paramater or passing the data coming back from the fs.readFile method... e.g. `callback(attacks)` or `callback(fileData)`. then inside your callback you can do whatever is required, e.g. sorting, returning a specific value, etc

Comment: Since you are already using async functions, it will be easiest to use the fs.promises interface instead of callbacks. Instead of `fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {...})` use `const files = await fs.promises.readdir(directory)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the empty log here because the node does not wait to finish while loop Hence you are getting empty log. Basically, you can improve this code by using the async-await method.

But if you are stick with this code, I am just suggesting this logic.

Just bring your log inside an if condition block. which have condition "print only if expected file count reached"

for example.

```
if(fileNum === files.length) {
    var keys = Object.keys(attacks);
    console.log(attacks);
}
```

So now log print only when this condition is satisfied which means after completion of while loop